# How to add a Param or variable in a react native Map Link

Tags: react-native, expo

```js
export default function ViewData({ route, navigation }) {
  const { email, id, rideID, Source, Dest } = route.params;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(email)}</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(id)}</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(rideID)}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL("google.navigation:q=" + { Source })}
      >
        <Text>CLick here to navigate to customer</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{Source}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Im New to coding on react native can't figure this out my Variables are there just not passing to the link.

Source= 39.0437567 -77.4874416

If i paste the Lat and log into google maps it takes me there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this function and it work for me

first `import {Platform, Linking} from 'react-native';`

this function open **google maps in android** and **apple maps in ios**

```
const openMapApp = (latitude, longitude) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Linking.openURL(`google.navigation:q=${latitude},${longitude}`);
    }else{
        Linking.openURL(`http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=${latitude},${longitude}`)
    }
};
```

this function open **google maps in android and ios**

```
const openGoogleMapApp = (latitude, longitude) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Linking.openURL(`google.navigation:q=${latitude},${longitude}`);
    }else{
        Linking.openURL(`https://www.google.com/maps/?daddr=${latitude},${longitude}`);
    }
};
```

Comment: The ${lat and long} does not output my variable I've tried that.

Comment: try latitude,longitude with comma not latitude longitude with space

Comment: The Param or Variable i need is $Source

Comment: onPress={() => Linking.openURL("google.navigation:q=" + { Source })}

Comment: Thanks Got it Not sure why it wasn't working before.